# Multiplying two sums?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

(Real-analysis only)

I will admit, I have posted a question **similar** to this, but this question's aim is to ask how to multiply the sum and integrate it.

$\displaystyle \log^2(x) = (2)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_k(1-x)^{k+1}}{k+1}$

$\displaystyle \log^2(1-x) = (2)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_k(x)^{k+1}}{k+1}$

the goal is to multiply the logs and take the integral from 0 to 1.

$\displaystyle \log^2(1-x)\log^2(x) = (4)\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_k(1-x)^{k+1}}{k+1}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_k(x)^{k+1}}{k+1}$

The integral:

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\log^2(x)\log^2(1-x) = \int_{0}^{1} (4)\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_k(1-x)^{k+1}}{k+1}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_k(x)^{k+1}}{k+1} dx$

How will we compute the RHS? Can we shift around the integral of sum or what can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: See [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).